# Having a function execute different pieces of logic depending on the parameters it receives

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a JavaScript function similar to the following:

```
setCookies: function (redirectUri, code, profile, response) {
    var serviceRedirect = settings.getServiceUrl(),
        state = code ? code : uuid.new(),
        redirectCookie = profile ? redirectUri + '?profile=' + profile : redirectUri;

    cookies.set(names.state, state, response.config);
    cookies.set(names.redirectUri, redirectCookie, response.config);
}
```

Because these values depend on the correct parameters being passed in, how can I defend against someone calling this function like: `setCookies('http://localhost', response)` ?

In that case, wouldn't the `redirectUri` be set to `http://localhost` while the `code`  was set to the `response` ? In order to ensure that the correct parameters are set, do I need to call the function with `undefined` for the arguments I don't need? Example: `setCookie(http://localhost', undefined, undefined, response);` ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, or you could reorder the parameters so that response is 2nd, and then you wouldn't need to pass undefined to the other parameters.

Answer (score 1):

What you are basically looking for is [function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading), but JavaScript does not support that natively.

These are your options:

Take arguments as a single object.

```
function setCookies(args) {
  var redirectUri = args.redirectUri;
  var response = args.response;
  // ... and so on.
}

// and call it like:

setCookies({
  redirectUri: 'https://some.com',
  response: response
});
```

This is easier with [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) if you can use ES6:

```
function setCookies({ redirectUri, response, profile, code }) {
  // Check the variable and do your stuff
}
```

Or use the length of the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object and check for supported usages:

```
function setCookies() {
  switch (arguments.length) {
    case 2:
      return setCookiesWithJustUriAndResponse(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
    case 4:
      return otherSetCookies(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3]);
  }
}
```

You can also make more intelligent guesses by checking the type of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just order the parameters that you know are required first in the method signature.

```
function setCookies(redirectUri, response, code, profile) {
    var serviceRedirect = settings.getServiceUrl(),
    state = code ? code : uuid.new(),
    redirectCookie = profile ? redirectUri + '?profile=' + profile : redirectUri;

    cookies.set(names.state, state, response.config);
    cookies.set(names.redirectUri, redirectCookie, response.config);
}

setCookies('https://test.com', response);
```